# Retrieving table schema information using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to retrieve the table schema information using C#.

I used the `sp_help <table_name>` query to retrieve it, which works well when I execute it in query window but fail to retrieve it from C#. I want to retrieve all table information which is necessary for mapping between two tables such as name, datatype, size, isprimary, key, etc.

I had write down following code

```
SqlCommand cmd = sourceCon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("sp_help '{0}'", cmbSourceTable.SelectedItem.ToString()); //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
sourceDataTable = new DataTable(); 
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
sourceDataTable.Load(dr);
dr.Close();
```

It will returns only info about table that when it is created or not

Comment: please show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: I had write down following code
SqlCommand cmd = sourceCon.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("sp_help '{0}'", cmbSourceTable.SelectedItem.ToString());
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sourceDataTable = new DataTable();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            sourceDataTable.Load(dr);
            dr.Close();


It will returns only info about table that when it is created or not

Comment: Awadhendra - you can edit the question to clarify things - I've copied the code from your comment into the question for you...

Comment: Thanks, I will remember it next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a simple way to get schema of a table.
Just create a connection with any provider like SqlConnection object.
Create a command object for select query (select only top 1 record as you want only schema of table)
Execute that query which return a DataReader object.
Every DataReader object have a method called GetTableSchema() which returns DataTable object which have schema of a perticulat table.

This way you can easily get schema of any table with less effort.

Here I will provide a simple code for this

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("connString");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("select top 0 * from Person.Address",con);
DataTable table = cmd.ExecuteReader().GetTableSchema();
```

Now this table object have schema information of Person.Address table.

Comment: You can actually use `TOP 0` and not return any actual rows.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using sp_help, you could try the following options:

1) use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'
```

2) query sys.columns

```
SELECT c.*, t.name
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTable')
```

These are just 2 options that will return a single resultset. INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS doesn't tell you (e.g.) if a column is an IDENTITY column, wherease the sys.columns route does. There's more information you can get from the catalog views, just depends what else you need. Here's the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You might find it easier to play with the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views - you can build queries that will extract most of the data relating to the structure of and relationship between tables within a SQL Server database schema.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think `sp_help` returns multiple result sets so you'll need to use `NextResult`, there are more details here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311274 (the example is not `sp_help` specific but it should give you the general idea)

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use the GetSchema method from SqlConnection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136367.aspx

like so:

```
var tableSchema = con.GetSchema(SqlClientMetaDataCollectionNames.Tables, new string[] { null, null, "[tableName]" });
```

The string array is a 'filter', here you can find the columns you can filter on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254969.aspx

For other database servers and more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

sp_help doesn't work in your code?  maybe you need to include an execute statement: exec sp_help.  or maybe the application is running under an account that doesn't have permission for sp_help.

Answer (score 0):

Since .net 2.0 the SqlConnection class offers GetSchemaMethod you can use to retrieve the requested info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136364(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score -1):

See this one ... it explains how

[How To Retrieve Schema Information by Using GetOleDbSchemaTable and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309681)

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't actually address the specific case - which (one might reasonably assume) is SQL Server. Its fairly explicit about that in the second paragraph.